# Bootstrap space under menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Please help, i have menu and using bootstrap to style it. But I add another div under menu and it is space between. I post here only half of my menu full code is in demo
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/42481/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="navbar-header">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">PIN CLicker</a>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
    data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
  </button>

</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

 </div>
 </div>
 </nav>


  <div class="col-sm-12"  id="statsobal" 
     style="background:red;">
    <span class="upstats1" id="uppins">0</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: do you want to remove that space?

Comment: yes i want to remove it

Comment: Can you look on the dev tools to see where the CSS that creates the space comes from?

Comment: its seems like nav have margin 20px under itsself

Comment: but i set .class{maring:0;} and space is still here

Comment: wait i got solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes I have made:

**in html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse ip">
```

**in css**

```
.ip{
   #border:3px solid blue;
    margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse ip">
  <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="navbar-header">
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">PIN CLicker</a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">


                              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="mine.php">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="pokus.php">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>

                            <form action="includes/logout.inc.php" class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="POST">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit">logout</button>

                            </form >

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="singup.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="login.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
     </div>
</nav> 





<div class="col-sm-12"  id="statsobal" style="background:red;">
        <span class="upstats1" id="uppins">0</span>
        <span class="upstats" id="updolar">0</span>
      <span class="upstats" id="upticket">0</span>
    <span class="upstats" id="upautoclick">0</span>
     <span class="upstats" id="uplevel">0</span>
     <span id="uptotal">0</span>

 </div>
```

css:

```
.ip{
   #border:3px solid blue;
    margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for yout time. It was right solution but just for zour information i link first my css file and that was a problem. After link my ccs after bootsrapt work perfectly nav{margin,pading:0;}

Comment: happy to help you